# Limit order total for customer in magento2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, subtotal

Can we restrict customer for add to cart once his quote total crosses specific count?

For example i need to restrict customer add to cart action, once the subtotal in quote crosses 500. I have created customer custom attribute called order_limit, can we check this condition and restrict customer to do add to cart action?

I used below event in my events.xml

```
 <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
    <observer name="checkout_cart_add" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\RestrictCart" />
</event>
```

This is my observer code

```
class RestrictCart implements ObserverInterface{

protected $_objectManager = null;
protected $_messageManager;
protected $_customerSession; 
protected $quoteFactory; 
protected $_checkoutSession; 
protected $_customer; 

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer
){
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_customer = $customer; 
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

    try{
        if($observer->getRequest()->getParam('product', false)) {               
            $productId = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('product', false);
            $requestedQty = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('qty', false);
            $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($observer->getRequest()->getParam('product', false));
            $StockState = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');

            $resource = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
            $connection = $resource->getConnection();
            if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
                $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
                $cusomerData = $this->getCurrentCustomer($customerId);
                $order_limit = $cusomerData->getOrderLimit();
                $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
                $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
                if($subTotal > $order_limit){
                    $this->_messageManager->addError(__('Order limit Crossed!!!'));
                    return $this;
                }                   
        }


        return $this;
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function getQuoteCollection($customerId)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
    return $quote;
}
public function getCurrentCustomer($id){
    $customerObj = $this->_customer->create();
    $customer = $customerObj->load($id);
    return $customer; 
 }
}
```

This code is working fine only when we add product from detail page, how same thing can be used on updating cart?

Comment: Why you have tried to use `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` ? I donot think is good because this event does not called every time

Comment: okay @amit, i will go with plugin you suggested me

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a minimum order amount you can override the native magento feature to save time to invert functionnality.
The config is in : config > sales > minimum order amount.

Just override the function `validateMinimumAmount($multishipping = false)` of the file :

> vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php

Invert conditions l:2219

`if ($amount < $minAmount) {
  return false;
 }`

in

`if ($amount > $minAmount) {
 return false;
}`

and l:2230

`if ($baseTotal < $minAmount) {
 return false;
}`

in

`if ($baseTotal > $minAmount) {
 return false;
}`

should do the work.

Comment: This will reflect for all customers, can we do it for specific customers?
like i have created custom attribute for customer and setting limit for it, so his cart total should not cross it

Answer (score 0):

There are two places from where Magento check order minimum amount for order.

`validateMinimumAmount()`,

As check `validateMinimumAmount()` at `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` and `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address`

For your requirement, you have to create an **aroundPlugin** on `validateMinimumAmount`.

If you don't use multi-address shipping then you have you have to create plugin on `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address`.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address">
        <plugin name="order_amount_restrict_on_order_amount" type="VeddorName}\{Module}\Plugin\RestrictOrderamount" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin Class:**

```
<?php


namespace {VeddorName}\{Module}\Plugin;


class RestrictOrderamount {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $_scopeConfig
    ) {

        $this->_scopeConfig = $_scopeConfig;
    }

    public function aroundValidateMinimumAmount(
       \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $subject,
        callable $proceed,    
        $result    
      )
    {
        $quote = $subject->getQuote();
        $customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $quote->getCustomer();
        // only worked on loggedin Customer
        if($customerId > 0 && $customer){

            // Assume that yoi
            $order_limit = $customer->getCustomAttribute('$order_limit') == null
            ? null:$customer->getCustomAttribute('$order_limit')->getValue();
            $taxInclude = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'sales/minimum_order/tax_including',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $storeId
            );
            $taxes = $taxInclude ? $subject->getBaseTaxAmount() : 0;

           if($order_limit> 0 &&
                   $subject->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $taxes >= $order_limit)
           {
               return true;
           }else{
               return false;
           }

        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

### Limitation

- Order amount limit checking only happen on**customer attribute**
  `order_limit` when a customer is logged.
- Also `order_limit` attribute you have used extension attribute
  feature.

Comment: Hi Amit, can you please update me code,

Comment: wait , i will explain in brief

Comment: Yes, i will try this code, can you pls tell when the code executes,? Because i set order limit 100 for one customer, i tried adding product of qty 4 with price 30 each. still its adding to cart

Comment: validateMinimumAmount will run at Cart page.If the validateMinimumAmount is returning false then a customer cannot go to checkout page. if the user hit checkout page URL directly then they will redirect to cart [age

Comment: Yes, i used your code and tried putting die after customerId, but for me its not showing , i can still go with checkout,

Comment: I am trying to get customerId and put some condition but i am not getting any customerID from your code,

Comment: did't worked until I based plugin upon \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote